# Build errors: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found

Tags: rpm

I have a simple rpm build that just won't work - complaining about files that it thinks shouldn'tbe there (see below error) from what I have read all files in the %{buildroot} need to be specified in %files I have tried every which way of specifying and still getting the error.

```
 rpmbuild -ba test.spec 
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.D09NzA
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/test/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ exit 0
Executing(%build): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.ArCuJC
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/pure/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ exit 0
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.ViZRTE
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/test/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ exit 0
Processing files: Test-7_14_9-1.noarch
Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /home/test/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Test-7_14_9-1.x86_64
error: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
   /pure


RPM build errors:
    Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
   /pure


With config:

Summary: Test
Name:Test
Version: 7_14_9
Release: 1
Group: Pure
BuildArch: noarch
BuildRoot: %{buildroot}/pure
License: XXX
Vendor:XXX
Packager: xxxx@xxxx.com
Provides:Test

%description
Test

%prep
exit 0

%build
exit 0

%install
exit 0
%clean
exit 0

%files
%docdir /pure
```

Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`%docdir` doesn't package files. It just tells rpm that any packaged files in that directory are documentation.

From [Maximum RPM](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html#S3-RPM-INSIDE-DOCDIR-DIRECTIVE) (old but often still relevant):

> The problem is that %docdir only directs RPM to mark the specified directory as holding documentation. It doesn't direct RPM to package any files in the directory. To do that, we need to clue RPM in to the fact that there are files in the directory that must be packaged.
>
> One way to do this is to simply add the files to the %files list:
>
> %docdir /usr/blather
>
> /usr/blather/INSTALL
>
> Of course, if you go to the trouble of adding each file to the %files list, it wouldn't be that much more work to add %doc to each one. So the way to get the most benefit from %docdir is to add another line to the %files list:
>
> %docdir /usr/blather
>
> /usr/blather